# Wait for directLine.activity$ to complete before going to next step

Tags: javascript, azure, direct-line-botframework

I'm using the following code to listen to activities sent from the bot:

```
/* Listen to activities sent from the bot */
directline.activity$
  .filter(activity => activity.type === 'message' && activity.from.id === botId)
  .subscribe(message => {
    if (message) {
      console.log("Reply", message)
    twiml.message(message);
    }
});
```

It works but my code is proceeded to send the response (see below) before the activity listener completes:

```
context.res = {
       
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' },
       body: twiml.toString()
    };
```

The "twiml.message" part is assigning the response syntax to confirm with Twilio.

I tried "let x = await directline.activity$" but it did not work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction about waiting for the process to finish before going to the next step in the code?

This is my full implementation:

```
async function step2() {
/* Listen to activities sent from the bot */
directline.activity$
  .filter(activity => activity.type === 'message' && activity.from.id === botId)
  .subscribe(message => {
    if (message) {
      console.log("Reply", message)
    twiml.message(message);
    }
});

}




return step2().then(function(response) {



    context.res = {
       
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' },
       body: twiml.toString()
    };



}) //end return step2
```

I thought by using return step2 and "async function step2" it should wait for everything to complete before sending the response.

Comment: Have you tried to await the step2() method? example `return await step2().then(.....`

Comment: I tried that but it still completes function execution before the directLine.activity$ gets the first event.  Is there a way to wait for the event to be received and then run some code?  I put a "sendResponse" function in the directLine.activity$ "received activity" function but it is ignored and says "function execution completed successfully" too early.